# Creating a rank column based on two other (linked) columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (example data) which has the dates of different DVD recordings for different pairs of birds for numerous broods:

```
PairID   BroodRef  DVDdate
1        512       2004-05-22
1        512       2004-05-30
1        512       2004-05-26
1        588       2004-06-30
1        588       2004-07-04
1        588       2004-07-09
2        673       2004-07-19
3        543       2004-06-03
3        543       2004-06-07
3        543       2004-06-11
3        620       2004-07-19
3         39       2005-05-19
3         39       2005-05-23
```

What I'd like is a brood number for each pair, such as:

```
PairID    BroodRef    DVDdate    BroodNumber
1        512       2004-05-22       1
1        512       2004-05-30       1
1        512       2004-05-26       1
1        588       2004-06-30       2
1        588       2004-07-04       2
1        588       2004-07-09       2
2        673       2004-07-19       1
3        543       2004-06-03       1
3        543       2004-06-07       1
3        543       2004-06-11       1
3        620       2004-07-19       2
3         39       2005-05-19       3
3         39       2005-05-23       3
```

I have tried

```
ddply(df,.(PairID),transform,BroodNumber = dense_rank(BroodRef))
```

which I saw on another question, but this results in Pair 3, BroodRef 39 being BroodNumber 1 rather than the 3 it should be.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: How is this brood number calculated? It seems like there is some terminology that is domain specific. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'd like the BroodNumber to be calculated by separating the data into Pairs and then ordering the BroodRefs in ascending date order (not by ascending BroodRef order). Then the first set of identical BroodRefs would be number 1, next set number 2, and so on until the PairID changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(PairID) %>%
   mutate(BroodNumber = match(BroodRef, unique(BroodRef)))
#   PairID BroodRef    DVDdate BroodNumber
#    (int)    (int)      (chr)       (int)
#1       1      512 2004-05-22           1
#2       1      512 2004-05-30           1
#3       1      512 2004-05-26           1
#4       1      588 2004-06-30           2
#5       1      588 2004-07-04           2
#6       1      588 2004-07-09           2
#7       2      673 2004-07-19           1
#8       3      543 2004-06-03           1
#9       3      543 2004-06-07           1
#10      3      543 2004-06-11           1
#11      3      620 2004-07-19           2
#12      3       39 2005-05-19           3
#13      3       39 2005-05-23           3
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rleid()` from `data.table` to create a sequence based on `BroodRef`, grouped by `PairID`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,BroodNumber := rleid(BroodRef), by = PairID]
#    PairID BroodRef    DVDdate BroodNumber
# 1:      1      512 2004-05-22           1
# 2:      1      512 2004-05-30           1
# 3:      1      512 2004-05-26           1
# 4:      1      588 2004-06-30           2
# 5:      1      588 2004-07-04           2
# 6:      1      588 2004-07-09           2
# 7:      2      673 2004-07-19           1
# 8:      3      543 2004-06-03           1
# 9:      3      543 2004-06-07           1
#10:      3      543 2004-06-11           1
#11:      3      620 2004-07-19           2
#12:      3       39 2005-05-19           3
#13:      3       39 2005-05-23           3
```